# DSP what's the meaning of compute_res_attr_t?

Tags: signal-processing, qualcomm, hexagon-dsp

I read the code about the Qualcomm Hexagon 3.5.2 demo code:

```
D:\program\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.5.2\examples\common\benchmark_v65
```

and I encounter with the `compute_res_attr_t compute_res;` in the code,
I can't meet the definition of it , so what is it ? Thx!!!

I want to know the meaning of the `compute_res_attr_t` or where it is defined. Thx!!

Comment: does your SDK have this file `utils/sim_utils/src/sysmon_vtcmmgr_int.h` ?

Comment: thanks for your help, i found nothing about it in my SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This structure is defined like so in `Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/5.3.0.0/utils/sim_utils/src/sysmon_vtcmmgr_int.h`:

```
typedef union {
    unsigned long long attributes[COMPUTE_RES_MAX_LEN];
    struct {
        unsigned short ver;
        unsigned char bSerialize;
        unsigned char bVtcmSinglePage;
        unsigned int vtcmSize;
        void *pVtcm;
        unsigned int minPageSize;
        unsigned int minVtcmSize;
        unsigned char bHMX;
        unsigned char appId;
        unsigned char bCacheable;
        void *clientCtx;
        releaseCb releaseCallback;
        unsigned int outVtcmSize;
    } attr;
} compute_res_attr_t;
```